# How to delete custom provider from Data Exchange Framework

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I've created a test custom provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 and decided it's no longer necessary. How do I remove it completely and safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Delete Sitecore items

In [the documentation for creating a custom provider](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/def/20/data-exchange-framework/en/create-provider-in-sitecore.html), the paths that are created in Sitecore are listed and should be deleted:

1. /sitecore/system/Settings/Data Exchange/Providers/**your-provider-name**
2. /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/InsertOptions/Rules/DataExchange-**your-provider-name**Provider
3. /sitecore/templates/Branches/DataExchange/Providers/**your-provider-name**
4. /sitecore/templates/DataExchange/Providers/**your-provider-name**

## Delete custom code

In addition, make sure you remove any custom code you've added. If you followed the documentation, they will likely all be in a single namespace (e.g. `YourApplication.DataExchange.Providers.YourProviderName`).